# How to read Blob( image) data from mysql database and display on browser using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a table in database. In that table one filed is of type BLOB contains image on that.I want to read the  same image from database and want to display the image on jsp page by using  tag.

// using code in jsp is

```
              <% 
                 Blob image;
                 image=blogd.getImage();
                 out.println(image);
                 %>
                <img src="<%=image.getBinaryStream() %>>" width="300px"  height="300px" />



 //  out.println(image);
  output of this particular line is
 org.hibernate.lob.SerializableBlob@c7014c
```

- blogd is the object of Persitance java classs.

Comment: First of all, don't use java code in JSP. Better to use JSTL & write business logic in server side.

Comment: Get image data from DB, create output stream from response object, set the image type & write contents to output stream object. It will create image in JSP page.

Comment: http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/article-992927.html. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {  
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(image.getBinaryStream());
    out.flush(); 
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // close the connexion;
}
```

Comment: i have to add in this <img> tag.                                                              <img src="<%=image.getBinaryStream() %>>" width="300px"  height="300px" />

Comment: Then u have to create temp image file somewhere in the project directory or at suitable location & give the path of that directory including image file name in `<img>` tag.

Comment: @RequestMapping("/userblog.do") 
 public String getblog(HttpServletRequest req)throws ServletException{
  
 List<WriteBlogData> blogdata=service.getAllBlog();
 if(blogdata!=null){
 Iterator it=blogdata.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
  Object obj=it.next();
  WriteBlogData bdata=(WriteBlogData) obj;
  Blob img=bdata.getImage();
// from here how to store in a folder 
 }
 
 }
 }

Comment: U hv `Blob` data. U can *get stream of bytes* calling `blob.getBinaryStream();`. Then create one `OutputStream` to write content into it. Follow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-into-file/) tutorial.